# How to merge a user signed up by facebook with an exising user signed up with the same email

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am using parse in an iOS app and there are two ways of signup, either using email/password or Facebook login.

The problem happen when a user sign up using his email/password then logout and try to sign up using his Facebook account which have the same email.

I am using `[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:block:` to signup with Facebook which creates a new user object in the `Users` table in Parse

Now I have two records for the same user and I can not update the record that has the Facebook information with the user email because Parse will not allow duplicate emails

So what should be the best solution to solve this problem?

## UPDATE

I have used @kRiZ solution to login using plain Facebook code then either create new user or link the user with the Facebook data

```
- (void)loginWithFacebookWithSuccessCallback:(APISuccessCallback)successCallback
                          andFailureCallback:(APIFailureCallback)failureCallback {
    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: permissionsArray handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             failureCallback(error);
         } else {
             FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender" parameters:nil];

             [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id fbResult, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSString *email = result[@"email"];
                     User *existingUser = [self getUserByEmail:email];

                     if (existingUser == nil) {
                         [self signUpNewUserWithEmail:email];
                     } else {
                         // Need to set the current user to existingUser
                     }
                     [self linkCurrentWithAccessToken:result.token
                     successCallback(@{RESULT:RESULT_OK});
                 } else {
                     failureCallback(error);
                 }
             }];
         }
    }];
    
}
```

Now the problem is to assign the [PFUser currentUser] to the existing user in case it is already exists

Comment: it's incredibly difficult to solve this problem.

Comment: i have the same problem .... did you end up solving this fully ? ... if so  ... how

Comment: When you call this `[self signUpNewUserWithEmail:email];` don't you need to pass in a password? But then there is no password in this case since the user logged via Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can try linking the new Facebook user to an existing user on Parse using the `[PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:*...` methods.

```
if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:user withReadPermissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Woohoo, user is linked with Facebook!");
        }
    }];
}
```

See Parse [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-linking) on linking.

1. Login via Facebook (do not save user yet)
2. Query the user table for user having the same email as this new FB user
3. If found, link, else, save as new user.

UPDATE:

Linking method with FB access token:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:user
                      withAccessToken:accessToken
                                block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: That can't be done in my case as the user is logged out, i.e. `user` is null

Comment: regarding `Login via Facebook (do not save user yet)` the problem is that `[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:block:` already creates a new user object. What method should i use to login using Facebook instead of this one?

Comment: Yes, I used plain Facebook SDK to login to Facebook. This would return to you a `FBGraphUser`.  Upon successful login, you can check and link. See update for another link method.

Comment: I did your solution but now I am stuck at assigning the current user to the retrieved user from the user query, so do you know how to assign the current user to an already existing user in iOS?

Comment: `getUserByEmail` is done synchronously or asynchronously? It would be better not to use a method and perform the if/else part in the user fetch completion block function